# Search for non empty list inside a list using Java 8 features

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a code fragment that I want to make more concise yet readable
using Java 8 features like lambdas/streams etc.

Basically, there is a list of items and each item has a list of errors.
If there is at least one item with at least one error, "failure" needs to be returned. If no items with any error, return "success".

```
Optional<List<Item>> optionalItemList = Optional.ofNullable(message.getItems());

if (optionalItemList.isPresent())
    for (Item item : optionalItemList.get()) {
        Optional<List<Error>> optionalErrorList = Optional.ofNullable((item.getErrors()));
        if(optionalErrorList.isPresent())
            if (!optionalErrorList.get().isEmpty()) {
                return "failure";
            }
        }
        return "success";
```

Answer (score 11):

`Optional` is not meant to replace `if` statements, but to be used as a return value of methods. So I think you'd better not use it for this task. You can use the ternary operator along with `Stream.allMatch` instead:

```
return message.getItems() == null || 
       message.getItems().stream()
              .allMatch(i -> i.getErrors() == null || i.getErrors().isEmpty()) ?
      "success" :
      "failure";
```

On a side note, methods should never return `null` collections. The absence of elements should be expressed by returning empty collections. This would have made your code a lot easier:

```
return message.getItems().stream().allMatch(i -> i.getErrors().isEmpty()) ?
      "success" :
      "failure";
```

Comment: +1 for "Optional is not meant to replace if statements" and "Return an empty collection instead of null." If I could upvote this twice, I would!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `flatMap` to search a list within a list. I personally think that a `List` should **never** be `null`, instead it should be an empty list. If that's a guarantee, then the code could be this:

```
boolean hasError = message.getItems().stream()
    .flatMap(t -> t.getErrors().stream())
    .findAny()
    .isPresent();
return (hasError ? "success" : "failure");
```

Otherwise, the code becomes a little longer:

```
boolean hasError = Optional.ofNullable(message.getItems()).orElse(List.of()).stream()
    .flatMap(t -> Optional.ofNullable(t.getErrors()).orElse(List.of()).stream())
    .findAny()
    .isPresent();
return (hasError ? "success" : "failure");
```

Note that I could have also used `.count() > 0` instead of `.findAny().isPresent()`. But the disadvantage of the former is that it iterates over all errors, while the latter short-circuits if any error is found.

Answer (score 2):

To me you have made it overly complex. Here's a much simpler way of doing it. Make sure your  `getItems()` method returns an empty list if there are no items to return, so that you can dispense with additional null checks as above. This approach is less error prone and leads to more readable code. If you can do the same for `getErrors` method above, you can merely dispense with the `filter(Objects::nonNull)` and that will further simplify the stream processing pipeline.

```
String errorPresent = message.getItems().stream()
    .map(Item::getErrors).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(List::size).filter(s -> s > 0)
    .findAny().map(ignored -> "failure")
    .orElse("success");
```

Alternatively you may use the ternary operator to get this thing done.

```
String errorPresent = message.getItems().stream()
    .map(Item::getErrors)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .anyMatch(e -> !e.isEmpty()) ? "failure" : "success";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `anyMatch` for the iterative code as :

```
Optional<List<Item>> optionalItemList = Optional.ofNullable(message.getItems());
if (optionalItemList.isPresent())
    if (optionalItemList.get().stream()
            .map(item -> Optional.ofNullable((item.getErrors())))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .anyMatch(optionalErrorList -> !optionalErrorList.get().isEmpty())) {
        return "failure";
    }
return "success";
```

or further simplify it as :

```
return Optional.ofNullable(message.getItems())
        .filter(a -> a.stream()
                .map(item -> Optional.ofNullable((item.getErrors())))
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .anyMatch(optionalErrorList -> !optionalErrorList.get().isEmpty()))
        .map(a -> "failure")
        .orElse("success");
```

Comment: Review: Just check if there is a critical pair of braces missing in the question.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable((item.getErrors()))` could be replaced with `Optional.ofNullable(item.getErrors())`.